# I updated my Wordpress to 4.8. Now page not found error is coming

Tags: wordpress

I updated to WordPress 4.8 and after that my pages url has got changed and now it is showing:

> Sorry, but we couldn't find the page you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the permalinks at wp-admin and look at the links of your posts, they might be changed